# how do I fix (dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 211; 2 is required) error?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views, django-errors

I need when someone registers a new account to add errors if there any. now, I tried to raise an error by ValidationError the first time seems to me it has triggered but when I closed the IDE and opened it again it shows me the next error:
**Exception Type:   ValueError

Exception Value: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 211; 2 is required**
I have no idea what happened exactly? and why that error appears while it didn't appear before I close the IDE?

views.py

```
# User registration
class Register(CreateView):
    template_name = 'account/register.html'
    form_class = SignUp
    success_url = reverse_lazy('account:login')
```

forms.py

```
# UserCreationForm
class SignUp(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'password1',
                  'password2',
                  'email']

    def clean_username(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if User.objects.filter(username=data).exists():
            raise ValidationError('username is already exists')
        return data

    def clean_email(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.objects.filter(email=data).exists():
            raise ValidationError('email is already exists')
        return data
```

register.html

```
                    <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="right-inner-addon">
                            {% for field in form %}
                                {% if form.errors %}
                                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                                    <div class="text-danger">
                                        <strong>{{ error }}</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                {% endif %}
                            {{ field }}
                            {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <hr>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade in active text-center" id="pp">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create Account</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**{{ form }}** is not list of dictionaries to loop through it; it is dictionary of dictionaries where each key represents field and each field is a dictionary which has key called **errors** which will be list of errors.
so you need to know the name of fields that will be displayed and depending on that you display errors, for example:

```
<input name="old_password" type="password" class="form-control" id="id_old_password">
            {% for error in form.old_password.errors %}
                <p style="color:red">{{ error }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
```

**Note here**: to make your field be able to send request to CBV (as in your case) and give CBV the ability to handle POST & GET request without any problems you need to provide **id="id_field name"** and **name="field name"**.

Comment: the error here is not raising because of Html the error was working well by the code of HTML I did but when I stopped the server and I did run again the server sends me that error. also if I did run for server the server will run well at least will return me the page without any error and doesn't execute anything raising and when I try to send the request it returns me that form is invalid, however, I tried what you told me and the error is the same